# Return a list containing all values greater than N of each matrix row in R

Tags: r

Given a matrix in R like the following:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    0    8
[2,]    7    1    9
[3,]    9   13    5
```

I would like to get a list with numbers that are greater than a given N **by row**.

For the example of N=7, the result should be:

```
[[1]]
[1] 8

[[2]]
[1] 9

[[3]]
[1] 9 13
```

I don't know if it can be done efficiently using functions like `apply`, `lapply`, `sapply`... or if I should use conventional loops (`for`, `while`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apply` with `MARGIN=1` will apply a function across all the rows of the matrix.

```
m <- matrix(c(2, 7, 9, 0, 1, 13, 8, 9, 5), ncol = 3)
N <- 7

apply(m, 1, function(r) r[r>N])
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 8
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 9
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1]  9 13
```